# Telnet with optional login/pw and sending commands using perl

Tags: json, perl, networking

Ok Im new to perl script and trying to make a code and have searched the posts here related to telnet and logging and sending commands... I tried the same but did not work

Heres json file

```
{
"testbed": {

    "rps": {
        "RPS1": {
            "management": "192.168.40.2",
            "pool": "2,4,5"
        },
        "RPS2": {
            "management": "192.168.40.20",
            "pool": "2,5"
        }
    },

}
```

And my perl script is this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use warnings;
use strict;
use JSON;
use Talari::Automation::CLI;
use Data::Dumper;
use Net::Telnet();
use Expect;


#read json and print value of json
my $json;
{
  local $/; #Enable 'slurp' mode
  open my $fh, "<", "Persistent_path.json";
  $json = <$fh>;
  close $fh;
}
my $data = decode_json($json);

############RPS
use vars qw/ $rps $rpses $ip /;



#rps info from decoded $data alone stored in $rps of perl
my $rps = $data->{'testbed'}->{'rps'};
print Dumper($rps);

# loop to extract only mgt ip addresses of switches
foreach my $rpsinfo(keys %{$rps})
{
    my $rpses=$rps->{$rpsinfo};
    my $rpsip = $rpses->{'management'};
    my @rpspool = $rpses->{'pool'};
    my $telnet = Net::Telnet->new( Timeout=>5, Errmode=>'die', );
    $telnet->open("$rpsip");
    $telnet->waitfor('/\> $/');
    $telnet->cmd('pshow');
}
```

and the output is pattern match timed-out at ./rps.pl line 38
and when logging in telnet manually, the prompt shows only >

I just wanted to login to telnet as easy as possible so I searched and saw Telnet module but its not giving output.
I also tried this code

```
system("telnet","$rpsip");
```

It works but I cannot send any commands like "pshow" using print command..

Anyone help me with this? I just want to make it simple and also, I have to modify code so that incase the connection fails, i want to try for 2 more times logging in then issue my commands to turn the ports on.

Thanks in advance. Also, is there a place where I can learn perl script mostly related to networking?

Comment: `Pattern match timed-out at ./rps.pl line 38`: Use the debug features of `Net::Telnet` to see what prompt actually gets sent: `Dump_Log   => $filename,` : `my $telnet = Net::Telnet->new( Timeout=>5, Dump_Log => 'telnet_debug.txt', Errmode=>'die', );`

Comment: That was little helpful. Now I know exactly where the issue is occurring. Script is logging in telnet but I think its not able to recognize prompt and send the "pshow" command I believe 
This is how my telnet login page shows
<pre>`code`
>  >Type "help" for a list of commands.
>  >Make sure to set Telnet mode to Local Echo Off
>  >
<pre>`code`

Comment: That was little helpful.I used Input_log instead dump_log. Dump log shows in encrypt form. Now I know exactly where the issue is occurring. Script is logging in telnet but I think its not able to recognize prompt and send the "pshow" command I believe 
This is how my telnet login page shows
`code`
  >Type "help" for a list of commands.
  >Make sure to set Telnet mode to Local Echo Off
  >
`code`
Can you tell the regular regex format I should use in waitfor()?? 
*ignore previous comment.. im new and it says I can edit only 5 times*